# Global socket.io - Angular2

Tags: angular

With Angular2, what is the best way to share a global (socket.io) object between components? Especially from the RootComponent to a ChildComponent.

In my app.component.ts, I store a socket like this

```
export class AppComponent {
  socket: any;

  constructor() {

    this.socket = io('localhost:3000');
  }
}
```

And then try to reference it through app:ApplicationRef this

```
export class FileListComponent {
    app: any;
    constructor(app:ApplicationRef) {
        this.app = app;
        this.app.socket; // <==
    }
}
```

But this.app doesn't hold a direct reference to the instance, and couldn't find it either.

Is there a best practise for that?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best way to share WebSocket data between multiple components in Angular 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025837/the-best-way-to-share-websocket-data-between-multiple-components-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to initialize the socket io('localhost:3000') in a shared service (@Injectable), and than Inject that service wherever you want. This is the best way of sharing anything between components

This could easily help you create one: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html