# *ngFor loop with async pipe and hot socket connected observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, sockets, rxjs

Suppose we have alerts rendering into a list using `*ngFor` like this:

```
*ngFor="let alert of alerts | async"
```

Is it possible to have the `alerts` property be a hot observable that is being pushed to by the server and causing the list containing the alerts to refresh correspondingly?  If so what type of Observable(s) would be appropriate in this type of context?

Comment: That's what the async pipe does - unwraps an observable and updates whenever new data is received. Have you tried this and it's not working? Or are you just asking if conceptually your approach is correct?

Comment: I was hoping for an example where the `Observable<Alert[]>` is initialized in `ngOnInit()`, but remains in contact with and is being pushed to by the server, thus causing the table to update automatically with fresh alerts.  All the examples I have seen thus far refresh the Observable by making a new http client rest request, replacing the observable reference with a new cold observable returned from the http request.  It also looks like the entire table would have to be rerendered in this case.

Comment: Does Angular have a way to both receive delta updates to the observable that are Hot updates (In other words they are adding to the current state of the obserable) not replacing it, and does it also have a way to render the updates, additions, deletions only (I think that's what react does ... ) ... might be a different question ...

Comment: Well, react works with immutable state, so it pushes an entire state, which is exactly what rxjs does. I believe they work exactly the same. By using a "hot" observable, you close on a reference to an object, and modify that object, thus breaking immutability. It's not the end of the world, but when doing state it is pretty widely agreed upon that immutability should be used when possible.

Comment: After re-reading your request, it sounds like you want an observable with a `websocket` connection, not to http rest calls, is that right? That way, as new data is published from the server, your websocket connection will read it and update the observable, rather than issuing a new http request each time it grabs data. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I think I know what you mean.  Hmmm - I'm starting to realize that I'm looking for an observable where values are cached but can also be deleted (Which I don't think fits the observable definition).  So for example if an alert is cleared, then it is removed from the observable cache and the table refreshed by only deleting that one row.

Comment: Yes to the websocket question.

Comment: In that case, I would look into "websockets with rxjs", there are a few good articles and libraries out there. I have not personally used any of them, so I can't give any recommendations, but that should get you started

Comment: OK great thanks!  Taking a peek now.

Comment: [This stack Q&A may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968054/websocket-in-angular-4-and-rxjs-confusion)

Comment: Super thanks - also just found this which seems to hit the sweet spot: https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-socket-io-tutorial/#turning-websockets-into-rxjs-subjects

Comment: Sweet, thanks for reporting back. I know I will be doing something like this in the near future, so having a good reference will be handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `async` pipe subscribes to the Observable for you and subsequently cleans up the Subscription when it is no longer needed. You can apply the `async` pipe to any Observable, hot or cold, and it will create a new Subscription to render the content of that Observable to the template (or pass it to a child component through an input). For example, let's say I have an `alerts$` Observable:

```
alerts$: Observable<Alert[]> = alertService.getAlerts();
```

And I want to render a list of those alerts, like you show in your question:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let alert of alerts$ | async">{{ alert }}</li>
</ul>
```

I can also subscribe to the alerts$ Observable in my template and do stuff with the data there.

Let's make another property to hold the alert and a property to hold the subscription for cleanup.

```
mostRecentAlert: Alert;
alertsSubscription: Subscription;
```

And give it a value in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.alertsSubScription = alerts$.subscribe((next: Alert[]) => {
    mostRecentAlert = next[0];
  }
}
```

Then clean it up in the `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
 this.alertsSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

`alerts$` is now technically a "hot" Observable because it has an active subscription, but you can still use it in your template as before.

In short, the `async` pipe is just a handy tool for subscribing to Observables in the template. It allows you to render asynchronous data without handling any of the clean up.

To answer your question about what *type* of Observables would be appropriate for this context: whenever you are getting data through some sort of service or store (if you're using ngrx or something similar), it will most likely arrive as a stream. Even Angular's Http utilities use rxjs Observables. This allows you to use all of the powerful rxjs operators to mold your data into the form you want and just leave that final Observable "cold" in your component class. Then just throw the `async` pipe on it in your template and you have a very neat way to render asynchronous data or pass it into other components.

Comment: Great explanation

Comment: Great answer - do you know if there is a way to keep the observable reference connected in real time to the alertService?  I assume in the above case that a user would have to click a button or trigger some event that causes the alertService to refresh the alert observable?

Comment: @Ole Yes, that is called a websocket connection